# better way to ensure validity of passed params or variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, optimization

I've seen many code and one thing that stood out was checking the validity of parameters passed. For e.g.

1) if the `string` passed in parameter was actually a valid `string`

```
 + (BOOL)isEmptyString:(NSString *) string {
      if (!string || ![string isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) return YES;
      NSString *_string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
      return (!_string.length || [_string isEqualToString:@"null"]); 
 }
```

2) or if the parameter is truly a `dictionary` etc.

This leads to checks of validity at many many places in the code. What is the best way to prevent it? and at the same time ensuring that `string` and `dictionary` passed are actually correct?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is only one right way to do this.

In my projects I enable 'Threat Warnings as Errors' in target settings and set `-Wall -Weverything -Wno-objc-missing-property-synthesis -Wno-gnu -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-assign-enum` warnings flags.

This 'paranoid' mode will not allow the developer to pass the data with wrong type to the method.

Second thing is asserts. 
So in your case I would do something like this:

```
+ (BOOL)isEmptyString:(NSString *) string {
    NSParameterAssert([string isKindOfClass:[NSString class]];
    ...
}
```

Thus during development I will see that something goes wrong.

And the last. If you think that in the Release build method can get the wrong data type, then you still have to do a check:

```
if (![string isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    //Log an error
    //Decide what do in this case. (Send log, Show error message to user, throw exception ...
}
```